# Is `java.nio.file.Files.createFile` a blocking call?

Tags: java, scala, asynchronous, file-io, io

Does `java.nio.file.Files.createFile` block calling thread? If yes, 
what is a non blocking async alternative to create a file/directory?

I am looking for a simple solution that can work in java or scala.

Comment: `Future(createFile)`

Answer (score 3):

All operations in *Files API* are blocking. The only way to perform `createFile` non-blocking way is to use some kind of concurrent wrapper, that would execute that operation on other thread.

You could for example use [Future](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html) from the scala's standard library:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.blocking
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object BlockingIOExecutionContext {
   implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(
      Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
   ) // create seperate thread pool for our blocking operations
}

import BlockingIOExecutionContext._ //importing our execution context for blocking operations
// alternatively if you're doing only very few IO calls just use default ExecutionContext
// import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val createFileFuture: Future[Path]  = Future {
  blocking { //mark this operation as blocking
    Files.createFile(Paths.get("hello"))
  }
}

createFileFuture
  .map(_.getParent) // Future is monad, so you can use map/flatMap
  .onComplete{
     case Success(parentsPath) => /* do something when file is created */
     case Failure(exception) =>  /* do something when creation fails */
  }
```

When you're doing a lot of blocking IO operation it's a good idea to use a separate thread pool.
Using inner `blocking` block is also good practice because it lets the ExecutionContext know that you're doing the blocking operation. In case you will be doing more blocking calls at once, ExecutionContext can decide to add more threads to the thread-pool.

Please check this [article](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/4-concurrency-parallelism.md) for more tips on using scala futures.

There are also other alternatives like **cats-io**, **scalaz zio** or **monix task**, but if you're not using any of these libraries already I would just stay with **Future**.

Comment: Hmm.. this is what I am doing right now since I suspected it's blocking call. But something seems wrong. Why do I have to use another thread when I just want to perform is an IO operation? That seems like I just shifted a blocking op (which was not supposed to be blocking) to another thread! Would it be correct to say that JAVA does have true async capabilities for file IO?

Comment: Actually `Files.createFile` is Java IO library. As far as I remember all Java IO libraries like files API or JDBC are all blocking, so only way to make then `async` is by *shifting* to another thread. **Future** is just a high-level wrapper, that makes doing operation on other threads easier.

Comment: For example, for database connectivity, oracle is developing an async alternative to [JDBC](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/jdbc-next:-a-new-asynchronous-api-for-connecting-to-a-database). It is possible that in future new async API would be added to Java's standard library, but for now all ops are blocking.